# Render random class instance with custom form and random id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, render

I am trying to generate a random `Task` from the data base and render it on the page.

On the main page I have: `<%= link_to 'gen task', :action => :random_task %>`

in controller i have this 2 methods:

```
def show_random_task
@task = Task.find(params[:task])
end 

def random_task
    begin
      @task.id = nil
      @task = Task.find(rand(Task.first.id..Task.last.id)) rescue "Item couldn't been randomized!"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to show_random_task}
    end
end
```

show_rand_task.html.erb

```
<h1>Generated task</h1>
<% random_task %>
<%= form_for (:task, :url => {:action =>'show_random_task'}) do |f|%>

  <p><%= render(:partial => "show_rand_task_form", :locals => {:f => f}) %></p> 
<%end%>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Show', @task %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', tasks_path %>
```

the custom form is _show_rand_task_form.
My problem is: Where do I fail passing the random id, for showing it.
               Why od i get error on `show` method since i didn't call it.

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#sho
    Couldn't find Task with id=random_task
    Rails.root: xxxxxx
    app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:16:in `show'
```

PS: I am new to rails.

Answer (score 1):

It's nice idea to use redirect for random task url. I think such sequence can be handled by simpler code:

```
# in TasksController
def show
  if params[:id] == 'random'
    # order should be RAND() for Mysql, and RANDOM() for Postgres
    # there are better ways of doing it, but for this simple example:
    task = Task.order('RAND()').first
    redirect_to task
  else
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Then in view, you can put:

```
<%= link_to 'random task', task_path(:random) %>
```

I don't see why you need forms here, if all you do is just randomly selecting pre-existing record.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems and few optimizations which might be done to the code.

1 - The instance variable `@task` which you set in random_task is not passed to the show_random_task action. Redirecting goes through the whole response stack, and that includes an empty instance variable set.

2 - Change your random_task to:

```
def random_task
  @task = Task.find(rand(Task.first.id..Task.last.id)) rescue "Item couldn't been randomized!"
end
```

And rename the show_rand_task.html.erb to random_task.html.erb

There is no point in redirecting the show_random_task if all you want to achieve is rendering it. Rails will render random_task.html.erb by default at the end of the random_task action.